# c++ undefined reference to destructor

Tags: c++, reference, destructor, undefined

Sorry about this, but I am re-opening this. After sorting the eigen errors, this cropped right back up again. Exactly the same code exactly the same error. (well, the compiler found the eigen headers this time.) So, same question:

I have searched for destructor c++ and undefined reference to no avail. However I am pretty sure this is a fairly simple slip on my part.

### Error:

```
/tmp/ccDsaJ9v.o: In function `main':
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [geomTest] Error 1
```

### SASAGeometry.h:

```
class SASAGeometry
{
public:
//methods
  SASAGeometry() ;
  int makeFromFiles(char *, char *, char *) ;
  ~SASAGeometry() ;
//globals
  std::list<E......};
```

### SASAGeometry.cpp

```
SASAGeometry::SASAGeometry(){}

int SASAGeometry::makeFromFiles(char * xyz_file, char * dat_file, char * atoms_file)
{
  sasa_transformMatrix basisMaker ;
  list<Vect...
...
}

SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry(){}
```

### geomTest.cpp

```
int main(int argv, char * argc[])
{
  list<Vector3d>::iterator listIterator ;
  char * xyz_file = argc[1] ;
  char * dat_file = argc[2] ;
  char * atoms_file = argc[3] ;
  SASAGeometry geomMaker ;
  int geomErr....

...
return 0 ;
}
```

### makefile :

```
# compiler choice
CXX = g++

# executable path
BIN = .

# include paths (or lack thereof :p)
INCLUDE = -I .

# compilation flags
CXXFLAGS = -pipe # -O6

# linking flags
LFLAGS = -lm

# object declarations
GeomTest_OBJS = geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o

geomTest_source     = SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h geomSetup.cpp

SASAGeometry.o  :   SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h

geomTest.o  :   geomSetup.cpp SASAGeometry.o

# compile 
geomTest    : $(GeomTest_OBJS) makefile
            $(CXX) -o geomTest.o -o SASAGeometry.o $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(geomTest_source) $(LFLAGS)
            $(CXX) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/geomTest geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o $(LFLAGS)

clean       : \rm *.o *~ p1
```

My INCLUDE and LIBS flags are all ok, all other methods in the SASAGeometry class are quite happily defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since your destructor is trivial and non-virtual, why don't you just delete it and let the compiler provide you with one?

Comment: your link line doesn't appear to contain the `SASAGeometry` compiled object.

Comment: cheers Nim. This was it, I now have many issues with the including the eigen headers. Ah well, should be able to find THIS on the forum, thanks to all!

Answer (score 6):

You are not including `SASAGeometry.cpp` in makefile along with `geomTest.cpp`. makefile should be something like this:

```
geomTest    : $(GeomTest_OBJS) makefile
            $(CC) -o geomTest.o -o SASAGeometry.o $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(geomTest_source) $(LFLAGS)
            $(CC) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/geomTest geomTest.o $(LFLAGS)
```

Comment: Excellent, I am pretty sure this is what I was missing, as many more errors pertaining to not finding where my eigen library is held have cropped up. thanks ks1322.

Comment: Sorry about this, but I am re-opening this. After sorting the eigen errors, this cropped right back up again. Exactly the same code exactly the same error. (well, the compiler found the eigen headers this time.)