# c++ makefile destructor undefined reference

Tags: c++, reference, makefile, destructor, undefined

This is a puzzle to me:

[c++ undefined reference to destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7876105/1010873)

That's the issue, the code is the same as the link, full makefile and errors here. The linked answers did help but only to highlight that I had some headers in a place I did not expect.

### makefile

```
CXX = g++

BIN = .

LIBS = -L.

INCLUDE = -I . -I 

CXXFLAGS = -pipe # -O6

LFLAGS = -lm

GeomTest_OBJS   =   geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o

geomTest_source =   SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h geomSetup.cpp

SASAGeometry.o  :   SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h

geomTest.o  :   geomSetup.cpp

geomTest    : $(GeomTest_OBJS) makefile
            $(CXX) -o geomTest.o -o SASAGeometry.o $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) $(geomTest_source) $(LFLAGS)
            $(CXX) $(LIBS) $(INCLUDE) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(BIN)/geomTest geomTest.o SASAGeometry.o $(LFLAGS) 

clean       : \rm *.o *~ p1
```

I have both declared and instantiated the destructor AND not (allowing the compiler to do its thing)

### error

```
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
```

no other errors. (sorry if its preferable to bump seemingly sorted issues rather than link to them, but my effort at that didn't work)

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

MAKE SURE TO COMPILE THE CORRECT SOURCE FILES, NOT THE OLD ONES YOU FORGOT TO COPY.

Hi @trojanfoe and @Kerrick SB, both answers made me look at my makefile and realise it was ugly. Here is the revised version. I am still getting the same 'undefined reference to destructor' error though:

### makefile:

```
CXX = g++

BIN = .

LIBS = -L.

INCLUDE = -I. 

CXXFLAGS = -pipe # -O6

LDFLAGS = -lm

GeomTest_OBJS       =   sasa_transformMatrix.o SASAGeometry.o geomSetup.o

SASAGeometry.o      :   SASAGeometry.cpp SASAGeometry.h 

sasa_transformMatrix.o  :   sasa_transformMatrix.cpp sasa_transformMatrix.h 

geomSetup.o         :   geomSetup.cpp

geomTest                : $(GeomTest_OBJS)
                    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+

clean           : \rm *.o *~ p1
```

### error:

```
geomSetup.o: In function `main':
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5ab): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
geomSetup.cpp:(.text+0x5cd): undefined reference to `SASAGeometry::~SASAGeometry()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [geomTest] Error 1
```

Why would the linker complain about the destructor and not the constructor or any other methods/functions in the class?

Thanks again!

Comment: Please run your `make clean` and then `make geomTest` and the paste the complete output, not just the error, to your question.

Comment: You have not posted enough code for this makefile to work. The code you *have* posted does not compile. It's not minimal and neither is the makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your executable output file *and* your object file `geomTest.o` have the same name! That's bound to get you into trouble when the linker overwrites the object file.

Change it to `$(CXX) -o geomTest ...`, or better even to `$(CXX) $@ ...` to avoid such problems in the future.

In fact, you are misusing the linker command altogether: you just want to have *one* single `-o` option, and the objects are listed directly, without flags:

```
g++ -o myprog main.o foo.o bar.o
```

Within the Makefile, do yourself a favour and use magic macros:

```
myprog: main.o foo.o bar.o
        $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $+ $(LIBRARIES)
```

Here `-o $@` matches the target name, i.e. `-o myprog`, and `$+` matches all the dependent names, i.e. `main.o foo.o bar.o`.

The guiding idea behind using variables is that you should never say the same thing more than once if you can help it. So you can have `myprog: $(MyObjects)` as the rule, but then use `$+` in the command line to avoid repetition of `MyObjects`. This improves locality and maintainability.

Comment: And makes my makefile look semi professional... however, while teaching me a good few things about the compilation process and the pitfalls I skirt blindly daily, the error remains:

Answer (score 2):

The `-o SASAGeometry.o` in the `geomTest` target looks highly suspect to me - you are overwriting one of the dependency objects (actually both dependencies).

Try this:

```
geomTest    : $(GeomTest_OBJS)
            $(CXX)  $(CXXFLAGS)  $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(GemoTest_OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

(note that `$LDFLAGS` is the conventional variable in which to hold linker flags, not `$LFLAGS` which is used with the `lex` tool).